# Shortcuts key replacemento with AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I just started using Autohotkey (I am a noob with it) for remapping some key combinations like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> (which is good if you are using your left hand) to be accessible while using your right hand.

My initial script is the following:

```
RControl & RShift::
{
    send {LControl down}{tab}{LControl up}
    return
}
```

It works fine, but while switching tabs in Visual Studio, for example, I cannot hold the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key to keep switching tabs, I can only switch between 2 tabs.

Does anyone know if it is possible to achieve this kind of functionality with Autohotkey?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `{ }` around the hotkey body. Hotkeys simply start with `::` and end with return. Braces are only needed in functions afaik.

`send {LControl down}{tab}{LControl up}` could be expressed easier by `send ^{tab}` which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. The tab-switch in VS also works with right <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>.

In either way, this does not work because of the `send {ctrl up}`. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> needs to stay pressed down in order for the "Active files" window to stay open. Try:

```
RControl & RShift::send {RCtrl down}{tab}
```